# How to use ml luis entity and list entity together in bot framework

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

When i try to use both list entity and ml entity together in bot composer i get the following error:

"Check STATUS with {@idtype} {@id=132354}" has mix of entites with labelled values and ones without. Please update utterance to either include labelled values for all entities or remove labelled values from all entities."

Check STATUS  with {@idtype} {@id=132354}   .Here idtype is list entity and id is ml entity.

Answer (score 3):

What that means is that, for a specific utterance you have to either add labels (the "=132354" part) to all entities in the utterance or remove them from all entities.

For your specific sample, since you should have the "132354" value included in the list definition, you could remove it from the utterance.

However, ml entities require (at least some) utterances with labeled entities, after all that's the only way the machine can learn what that entity looks like . So, wherever you label an ml entity, you should also label the list entity or any other entity in the utterance.

You can read more about this topic in the [Best practices for building a language understanding (LUIS) app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices) documentation page.

BTW an utterance with unlabeled entities is considered a pattern, you can read more about this in the [Patterns improve prediction accuracy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-patterns) page.

Comment: here id is a ml entity and idtype is a list entity. Now i want to assign some value to id .Can you help me with this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, could you elaborate please? What do you mean by "assign"?